# How DropNet returning metadata for root folder of dropox is where Is_Dir type is false

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

What is the path of root folder?

I tried

```
var metaData = client.GetMetaData(Request.Data.XName, null, false);
```

`<b>Xname</b>` is a `<u>path for folder</u>` which files we want to load.

My question is that waht is the root path of folder to load his files.

Answer (score 1):

The DropNet library uses API v1, which [is deprecated and being retired soon](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should migrate to [API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). There's an [official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet) you can use.

For reference though, on API v1, the root path is identified by a slash: `"/"`.

On API v2, the root path is identified by the empty string `""`. (Though non-root paths do still need a leading `"/"`.)